# RTL support in Python Sphinx

Tags: html, python-sphinx, right-to-left

Is there a way to use RTL (Right to left, like farsi, arabic, ...) text in [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) ?

When generating HTML from .rst files, the generated HTML is LTR(Left to right by default) and aligned left, and my question is how I can change it, and make it RTL, and be aligned right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check python's docutils [FAQ](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#can-i-produce-documents-in-right-to-left-languages). It explains how to use css and classes to mark text direction.

Answer (score 4):

you can try [Minoo](https://github.com/saeiddrv/SphinxMinooTheme)  theme which supports RTL languages like Persian.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693907/886607) you can use css. In [put a text in center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132104/886607) and [Right to left numbering problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36847050/886607), I mentioned that you can use class names like rtl and ltr for changing the direction of texts. [My website](http://yoosofan.github.io) is powered by [Nikola](https://getnikola.com). [My Persian gitlab guidance project](https://gitlab.com/yoosofan_course/Farsi_gitlab_guide) is simpler and more readable. Specially [farsi.css](https://gitlab.com/yoosofan_course/Farsi_gitlab_guide/blob/master/farsi.css) and the last line of [README.rst](https://gitlab.com/yoosofan_course/Farsi_gitlab_guide/raw/master/README.rst) may be more helpfull.