# Align center a paragraph with RestructuredText?

Tags: alignment, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Is there a way to have a paragraph align in the center of the page using restructuredText for pdf (rst2pdf)?

Comment: For sphinx users that come across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33493589/2988730

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
.. class:: center

This paragraph will be centered.
```

Comment: Good answer. Almost 100% applicable to sphinx as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33493589/2988730

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use center tag (as described above) on rst2html.py (Docutils 0.12), you should create a css file, namely mystyle.css by adding the following line to it:

```
.center {text-align: center;}
```

For converting your rst file, namely, myrst.rst to html file, use the following command

```
rst2html myrst.rst myrst.html --stylesheet=mystyle.css,html4css1.css
```

By using this method, the following code works well.

```
.. class:: center

This paragraph will be centered.
```

Comment: The original question was about rst2pdf (the reportlab PDF writer). For rst2html5 (Docutils), the class value "align-center" works with the default style sheets.