# Add a class to a table in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a table in rst, and I want to add a class to it, when compiling to HTML with Sphinx. According to [the docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class), adding a `.. class::` directive before the table should add the class to the table, but instead it adds a definition list.

The table code is:

```
.. class:: special

== == ==
a  b  c
1  2  3
== == ==
```

which results in:

```
<dl class="class">
<dt id="special">
<em class="property">class </em><code class="descname">special</code><a class="headerlink" href="#special" title="Permalink to this definition">¶</a></dt>
<dd></dd></dl>

<table border="1" class="docutils">
<colgroup>
<col width="33%" />
<col width="33%" />
<col width="33%" />
</colgroup>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr class="row-odd"><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-even"><td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Sphinx 1.3.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Sphinx [default domain](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/index.html#directive-default-domain) is Python and it contains a `class` directive which shadows the original Docutils directive with the same name.

To make it work, use [`rst-class`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#rstclass) instead:

```
.. rst-class:: special

== == ==
a  b  c
1  2  3
== == ==
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could instead wrap your table with a `.. table::` directive and use its `:class:` option:

```
.. table::
   :class: special

   == == ==
   a  b  c
   1  2  3
   == == ==
```

See the corresponding `docutils` docs [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#tables).