# sphinx, restructuredtext: color cell/row of a table

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to color a specific row in a table in sphinx?

I tryed using .. role:: which is related to a CSS file as discused in [sphinx, restructuredtext: set color for a single word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702865/sphinx-restructuredtext-set-color-for-a-single-word). However a :role: does not seem to work in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but there is using the CSS selector [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and [applying a class to the parent table element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493589/add-a-class-to-a-table-in-sphinx#33497002). Then your custom CSS would be something like:

```
table.myclass tr:nth-child(3) {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using the ["class" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class) and custom CSS for all rows except the first:

> The "class" directive sets the classes attribute value on its content or on the first immediately following non-comment element.

Placing the "class" directive at the end of the last cell of a row will use the directive argument as "class" attribute value on the next row's `<tr>` element.

Note: In "Sphinx", the "class" directive is renamed to "rst-class".

Example:

```
===============   =====================
cell 1 1          cell 1 2
                  
                  .. rst-class:: bg-red

cell 2 1          cell 2 2
===============   =====================
```

The custom CSS rule `.bg-red {background: red;}` will give the second row a red background.