# How to define the the height of the csv table in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm using this code to create a table from csv for my documentation in readthedocs:

```
.. csv-table:: Markram et al. Model & Network configuration file
   :file: ../config_files/Markram_config_file.csv
   :header-rows: 1
```

The CSV is large and has a lot of rows and columns. For columns, everything is fine since it just fits a few columns in the page and the others can be accessed by scrolling to the right in the table. 
However, all of the rows are placed in the the page and I cannot specify a particular "length" or "height" for the [csv table](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#tables). 
I tried to specify the height by `:height: 100px` but it's not defined for the tables. Is there anyway to specify that? [Here's](https://pastebin.com/J5FkcDhJ) a sample of what I'm using in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately before your `.. csv-table` directive, put this above with a blank line separating (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195021/2214933):

```
.. rst-class:: table-myclass

.. csv-table:: blah blah blah
```

The above will apply a class name to the rendered HTML table.

Then in your Sphinx theme, add a custom style.  Assuming you want to limit the height of each table row (not the table itself since 100px is pretty short for a lot of data) put the following:

```
table.myclass tbody tr {height: 100px;}
```

Adjust the CSS selector and style to taste.

See [how to create custom styles in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079202/2214933).

Comment: I created a file in `./_static/css/custom.css` and added `table.myclass tbody tr {height: 100px;}` into the file. Then I added `def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('css/custom.css')` to my conf.py according to [this](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html) link, but still my table is presented very long. Just to remind you, I want it to be short but scrollable.

Comment: I recommend to set the class argument value with the `:class:` option of the ["csv-table" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#csv-table-1) instead of the prepended "rst-class" directive.

Answer (score 1):

I added a file `_static/css/custom.css` with the following contents (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/4457290/3362993):

```css
table.docutils {
    display: block;
    height: <your_height>px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: <your_width>%
  }
```

and added the following line to `conf.py`:

```py
html_css_files = [
    "css/custom.css",
]
```

I found that the trailing list-comma was necessary for the css file to be recognized :shrug: