# Add some whitespace in reStructuredText table column

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have this reStructuredText table:

```
   ================ ===
   h1               h2
   ================ ===
   a b           c  .
   d e              .
   ================ ===
```

and it gets me something like this:

[image]

I need to space out the `a b c` text with some whitespaces. I tried adding some vertical bars, > character in front of the row, trying to preformat them  (with backquotes), tried with `` :code:`a b      c` `` ,  nothing seems to work.

The output will be latex.

Thank you!

P.S. Of course the goal is NOT to place `c` so far out but to be able to insert whitespaces in a more complex example.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689094/how-to-define-the-the-height-of-the-csv-table-in-restructuredtext/48694716#48694716. Does that help?

Comment: I will wait some more until I try it. My target is Latex, I doubt that CSS styles are on latex make path. But I didn't check so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have regular spaces (U+0020) between `a b` and `c`. In the output, they are collapsed into a single space. To avoid this, use non-breaking space characters (U+00A0) in the reStructuredText source.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space.

Comment: That's a bit hacky. What if the printer will screw the characters up? Other alternatives?

Comment: Why is it hacky? Why would the printer screw the characters up?