# Sphinx multiple spaces in text

Tags: whitespace, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to insert multiple spaces into some text in a Sphinx document. The text appears in the value portion of a definition list entry. Here is a sample of working text. I want to replace the `-` with spaces, or find some other way of getting a visual equivalent:

```
Satisfy all existing ``GitHub`` issues
   This is a cleanup activity in preparation for generating issues describing
   the work items needed to realize Release ``0.1.0``. |br|
   Status: **DONE** ----- Label: Infrastructure ----- Issue: ``1``
Define the content of development release ``0.1.0``
    This activity defines the full list of content for release ``0.1.0``. |br|
    **DONE** ----- Label: Development ----- Issue: ``2``
```

I tried using non-breaking spaces `|nbsp|` and escaping spaces ``\ \ \ \ \ ` but neither worked.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63772548/407651

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work:

```
Hello |nbsp| |nbsp| |nbsp| |nbsp| World.

.. |nbsp|   unicode:: U+00A0 .. NO-BREAK SPACE
```

It produces:

```html
<p>Hello         World.</p>
```

This creates the nonbreaking space character.